# How to get currently logged in Windows user Priveleges in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I have  a web application. i want to check whether the curently logged in user has admin privileges on the client machine which he uses to log into the web application

I have tried using the following methods

```
          HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
          HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
          HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];
          HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator");
```

But everything is returning the network service account details , but i neeed the client's privilege information

Thanks,
Sherin